# Can I say a spirit conveyed by something?

Tags: word-choice

Confucius already manifests a spirit perfectly conveyed by these words of a much later text : “ If a foreigner comes to China, and lives like a Chinese, then treat him as a Chinese. (self-made)

I am not sure about the notion that "a spirit conveyed by these words" is a good expression, although I know "message conveyed in.." is good. Shall I changed it into:

Confucius already manifests a spirit best embodied/best illustrated in these words of a much later text?

Comment: Belongs in http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: The fact that it is a teaching of Confucius I would think this may belong elsewhere because it is ancient text which has with great effort been translated into English. Often any rules to English are thrown out so as to keep the meaning as unadulterated as possible. Maybe I am not understanding the question.

Comment: *'The spirit of these words were manifested (or made manifest) much earlier by Confucius.'*

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you’re suggesting is, in my opinion, uncomfortably verbose.  How about:

> Confucius (*or* Confucius’ thought) prefigures/anticipates the spirit/sentiments of this much later text:

Also, I feel less anachronistic translation of the quote would use *as* twice, instead of *as* once and *like* once.  Hence (with some other minor, optional tweaks):

> “If a foreigner comes to China and lives as a Chinese, treat him as a Chinese.”

Answer (score 0):

"Convey" means "transport, carry a thing" or, as here, "communicate an idea, a feeling" (not anticipating).

"Mood", "disposition", "attitude", "state of mind", "frame of mind", "principle", "message", or "ethos" are, I believe, better than "spirit".